# what is the difference between parent and @ISA?

Tags: perl, inheritance

both parent and @ISA doing same working, what is use of parent and @ISA accordingly.

```
package Baz;
    use parent qw(Foo Bar);
```

or

```
package Baz;
    BEGIN 
    {
        require Foo;
        require Bar;
        push @ISA, qw(Foo Bar);
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking what `@ISA` does? It's consulted by method calls to find inherited methods.

Answer (score 9):

`use parent` is simply a concise way of doing a `require` and pushing the package name onto `@ISA` in one statement. It happens at compile time instead of a simple `our @ISA = qw/ Foo Bar /` which is done at run time, and means you have to code the package name only once which may reduce errors. It will also raise a warning if a package tries to inherit from a package of the same name, which would be useless and could cause an infinite inheritance loop.

In short, `use parent` is a more concise and easy way to get everything right.

Answer (score 5):

[`parent`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?parent) is syntactic sugar to set a package's `@ISA` variable and automatically load its superclasses at compile time. As the [`parent` documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?parent) states, there is no functional difference between the two code blocks in the OP.